# How to access $bvToast in vue class component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, bootstrap-vue

I'm pretty new to vue.js but I could figure out some things. I started with normal js but switched to typescript with class style vue components now. For components styling I use bootstrap-vue.

**in my main.ts file I imported bootstrap as well as the vuex store**

```
...
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue'
//use custom bootstrap styling
import '../src/bootstrap/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
Vue.use(BootstrapVue)

...//some more code

new Vue({
 router,
 store,
 i18n,
 render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

In the store I dynamically register a NotificationModule

**NotificationModule.ts**

```
//import node modules
import { Module, VuexModule, Mutation, Action } from "vuex-module-decorators";
import { store } from "@/store";

//import application modules
import i18n from '@/i18n';

import Notification from '../types/Notification';
import Message from '../types/Message';
import logger from '@/system/logger';

@Module({
    dynamic: true,
    store: store,
    name: "notification",
    namespaced: true,
})
export default class NotifcationModule extends VuexModule {

  //notification types definition with according prompts
  notificationTypes: Array<string> = ['info', 'success', 'warning', 'danger'];

  //definition of the notification object
  notification: Notification = {
      variant: '',
      prompt: '',
      message: ''
  }

  /**
   * prove the supported notification types
   */
  get getSupportedNotificationTypes(): Array<string> {
      return this.notificationTypes;
  }

  /**
   * provide the notification
   */
  get getNotification(): Notification {
    return this.notification;
  }

  @Action
  notify(msg: Message){

    logger.warn(`called notify with [type:${msg.variant}]:[text:${msg.text}]`);

    if(msg.variant === undefined || !Array.from(this.notificationTypes).includes(msg.variant)){
      msg.variant = 'info';
    }

    //configure custom notification data
    const notification = {
        variant: msg.variant,
        prompt: i18n.t(`notify.${msg.variant}`),
        message: msg.text || 'No message provided.'
    }

    this.context.commit('setNotification', notification);
  }

  @Mutation
  public setNotification(data: Notification) {
      if (data) {
          this.notification = data;
      }
  }
}
```

that all works. I can get an instance of this store in the vue-component that produces the notifications but I have a problem by creating a toast in the following vue component.

**Notification.vue**

```
<template>
  <b-container></b-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';
import { getModule, VuexModule } from 'vuex-module-decorators';
import NotificationModule from '../../util-notification/components/NotificationModule';
import Notification from '../types/Notification';
import logger from '../../../system/logger';

@Component
export default class UserNotification extends Vue {

  //get the instance of the NotificationModule
  noticationInstance: NotificationModule = getModule(NotificationModule);

  //watch the property 'notification' -> accessed via getter method
  @Watch('noticationInstance.getNotification')
  onPropertyChange(notification: Notification, oldValue: string) {
    logger.debug(`replaced [${JSON.stringify(oldValue)}] by [${JSON.stringify(notification)}]`);

    //create a toast
    this.$bvToast.toast(notification.message, {
      title: notification.prompt || 'Info',
      variant: notification.variant || 'warning',
      solid: true
    });


  }
}
</script>
```

here in the file Vetur gives me the following error although it compiles. But no toasts were produced and shown.

***Property '$bvToast' does not exist on type 'UserNotification'.Vetur(2339)***

I have created a TestView where I integrated the $bvToast differently and there it works.

```
<template>
  <b-container fluid>
    <h1>This is the page for testing components and functionality</h1>
    <hr>
    <div>
      <h3>Trigger für vuex notification test</h3>
      <b-button @click="$bvToast.show('example-toast')" class="mb-2">Default</b-button>
    </div>

    <b-toast id="example-toast" title="BootstrapVue" static no-auto-hide>
      Hello, world! This is a toast message.
    </b-toast>

  </b-container>
</template>
```

Do you have any suggestions about what I am doing wrong?
Thanks you

**Problem solved or better it works**

I don't really know why but it works now! without further changes. Sorry I can't reproduce this anymore. Also webconsole also doesn't show any errors.

So it seems I can access the vue instance within my UserNotification component. UserNotification extends Vue so it is a Vue instance not VueX. The discribed solution from the answer was not neccessary.

Is t possible tha only Vetur doesn't recognize the the $vbToast as a property of the UserNotification or even the extended Vue instance in the typscript context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `this` context of VueX is not a Vue instance, so `this.$bvToast` is not available directly.

There is a workaround however to access the main Vue instance within VueX.  Use `this._vm.$bvToast` instead.

See:

- https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1399
- https://github.com/bootstrap-vue/bootstrap-vue/issues/3502